# Are oscillations of electron chirality experimentally observable?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, electrons, neutrinos, higgs

Is there any plausible experiment by which chirality oscillations in electrons could be observed experimentally, such as through some analogy to neutrino oscillation experiments?

Comment: The presence of an electron mass...

Comment: @MichaelBrown can you be more explicit? The same electron mass for both chiralities?

Comment: The fact that an electron has mass produces oscillations between chiralities. The fact that you can stop an electron is proof that chirality is not a good quantum number for electrons. :) That said: there is a bid difference in scale between electron and neutrino neutrino masses. So to observe chirality oscillations you would need a short distance probe that treats the two chiralities differently, like... the weak interactions. :)

Comment: Indeed you see "helicity" supressed weak decays of the $\pi^\pm$. You could just as well call it chirality supression since what is being measured is the rotation between chirality and helicity eigenstates which is the result of the mass term.

Comment: Michael Brown, concur in particular about mass. While low in mass by most standards, the electron is flat-out *gigantic* in comparison to a neutrino. I tried to keep my question open for that reason, with the neutrino analogy just intended to say "such things do have visible outcomes... sometimes!" And I certainly agree that it would need to use the weak interaction, as I'm not aware of anything else that distinguishes the chiralities clearly (is there?). Sooo... maybe something like a specific way of reinterpreting of $\pi^{\pm}$ decays, as you may be suggesting, is the best that is possible?

Comment: As well as curiosity about actual data, it would frankly be nice for clarity of explanation if the answer to "are left and right handed electrons real particles?" was "yes, but only for exceedingly short periods of time, as demonstrated by [fill in the blank]". The view of left and right electrons as real but inherently unstable entities that oscillate quickly just seems to me to bring the whole concept more in line with the rest of particle physics, where short durations are common. The neutrino mass is so low that these oscillating states show up as real particles, so why not electrons, too?

Comment: Well, neutrinos are detected through the weak interaction, so it will be oscillation length . If for electrons this is of measurable order then one could create a beam of positive chirality  electrons (from the appropriate pion decay) and measure a capture rate on an appropriate nucleus. One needs numbers for this, but if it is linear in the mass and neutrinos are of order of ev, it might be doable since to see neutrino oscillations one needs kilometers.

Comment: @annav, if I'm following you rightly, that's... intriguing. If you feel your unavoidably somewhat speculative comment (since I gather no one has ever tried such experiments) is sufficiently grounded in reported physics to qualify as an answer (your call), I'll gladly give you the answer nod for this one if you copy it over or expand on it a bit as an answer.

Comment: hmmm. neutrinos oscillate between lepton numbers (tau mu e) . Here I am speculating about chirality, i.e. one starts with a beam of a certain percentage of right handed electrons and detects a change on that percentage oscillating in space. I am too rusty  to think up the matrix elements needed for this process and see if this is possible from QM. Anyway it needs numbers to be either rejected or thought as possible.

Comment: The fact you can flip the spin of an electron (via a Zeeman field) without changing its velocity (you can even stop an electron, for that matter, as @MichaelBrown mentioned)?

Answer (score 1):

In its rest frame an electron is always equal parts left- and right-handed chirality.